# can I add disclaimer for the questions which are perilously close?

Tags: discussion

I have experienced that some questions are stand on the verge of closing reasons. I got friendly warnings from other users about one of [my question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95882/does-smugness-imply-having-or-showing-low-opinions-of-others). But my question is good fit and not warrant for closing.

My specific question here is, In such situations can I add disclaimer in order to prevent that others mistakenly close the question. What other actions that I can take in order to avoid the question get closed? How can add more clarity to the question which moves away it from the verge of closing?

Comment: Please don't add a disclaimer, because that's not really adding much to the question--but what you *can* do is show your research. The answer has really been the same for all of the questions you posted: show your research.

Comment: The problem with that question is, if you ask me, that the example you quote is from a non-standard or low-quality text. It is rife with what I would call mistakes. Perhaps those mistakes are acceptable features of English spoken in India, but not in the Anglo-Saxon world, nor in other countries where people learn Anglo-Saxon English, if I may call it that. If you want to learn standard English, I advise you to make sure you don't pick up non-standard grammar from texts like that one. Read texts written in standard English (and by a skilled writer: many websites are poorly written).

Comment: @simchona: I believe I am showing the research my best. Do you think is there much to show here? If yes can you please explain what else that we can show in the given case. I am very happy to show that in my future posts.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and add the disclaimer! Format your disclaimer as follows:

1. The question is a real question because...
2. The question is not general reference because...
3. The question is constructive because...

Also say that you consulted the relevant sections of both OED and Huddleston & Pullum without finding what you were looking for.

Comment: @Babu Don't just *say* you consulted whatever references. *Link* to them and (preferably) *include the relevant section in your answer* as well. JR's and my answers to your previous Meta questions all say that.

Comment: @AndrewLeach i think that's good advice, but its appropriateness would be confined to a resource which (i) has a relevant entry, and (ii) is not behind a paywall. e.g., MW's dic. of usage has an entry for *economic/economical*, but it probably doesn't for *font/fount*.